# Actively take Influence on PoE Wattage delivered by Switch?

Tags: power-over-ethernet

I'm running a Raspberry Pi 2 as a Print-Server for a MFC-Printer with saned for scanning over network support. I have the Pi powered via a TP-Link [PoE-Splitter](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4794_TL-POE10R.html) with 5V output. The PoE switch is a D-Link [DGS-1210-10P](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DGS-1210-10P) (HW Rev C).

The Pi which works perfectly when powered from a wall-outlet is rebooting over and over again, and as far as I understand, this is due to the fact, that the Switch delivers only about 0.8W / 22mA through the port the Pi is connected to.

The Interface of the Switch only allows to *limit* but not to specifically set the Wattage that is sent through a specific port.

Is there some kind of trick or hack (e.g. by soldering a resistor in between or such) to force the Switch to deliver more Wattage? Or any other ideas / suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Uh, NO. The switch is designed to provide what it provides.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to provide power over Ethernet and your switch couldn't deliver enough power ,may you use power injector , a lot of brands may show a lot of power injectors with variety of o/p power . power injector is something work as in the next shape 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several PoE standards, and each has a maximum amount of power it can deliver. Apparently your switch can't deliver enough power, and there is nothing to be done about that except to replace the switch or use an external, in-line PoE adapter that delivers enough power.  You can't change the existing switch to use a newer PoE standard.

I see this problem all the time with the new 802.11ac WAPs.  They require PoE+, but people try to use them on PoE, and it just doesn't work.  With one or two devices, it makes sense to buy external PoE adapters, but for a lot of devices, you just need to replace the switch with one that supports the newer standards.

**EDIT:**

The data sheet for your switch shows a maximum of 78 Watts PoE for the entire switch.  Are you using PoE in other ports?  You could be exceeding the power budget for the switch.

Comment: There are 2 cameras requiring about 9W each, but that's all, so power budget should not be a problem and as I could push the limit up to 15W on one single Port I assume the switch *could* provide enough power?

Comment: Obviously, your PI needs more power than 802.3af provides. You need something better than the switch/splitter combination that you have. The answer to your question is that you can't modify your existing equipment.